# Entity Framework - Query an Adapter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, business-objects

I'm strugling with entity framework where I've made a library with Business Objects (i.e Account) which are used allover the system.

```
public class Account
{
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountText { get; set; }
}
```

The entity framework is then converting these forth and back when they are requested or required to save

```
public interface EntityAdapter<T> {
    T Materialize(long id);

    long Dematerialize(T business);
    void Dispose(T business);
}

public abstract class EFEntityAdapter<T> : EntityAdapter<T> {
    private static MyModel.MyEntities __ctx = null;
    protected MyModel.MyEntities _context
    {
        get
        {
            if (__ctx == null)
            {
                __ctx = new MyModel.MyEntities ();
            }
            return __ctx;
        }
    }

    public abstract T Materialize(long id);
    public abstract long Dematerialize(T business);
    public abstract void Dispose(T business);
}
public class AccountEntityAdapter : EFEntityAdapter<CommonLib.BusinessModels.Account>
{
    public override CommonLib.BusinessModels.Account Materialize(long id)
    {
        Account entity = (from account in _context.Accounts
                          where account.AccountId == id
                          select account).FirstOrDefault();

        if (entity == null)
            return null;

        CommonLib.BusinessModels.Account business = new CommonLib.BusinessModels.Account();

        business.AccountId = entity.AccountId;
        business.AccountText = entity.AccountText;

        return business;
    }

    public override long Dematerialize(CommonLib.BusinessModels.Account business)
    {
        long id = business.AccountId;

        Account entity = (from account in _context.Accounts
                          where account.AccountId == id
                          select account).FirstOrDefault();

        if (entity == null)
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Account with id: " + id + " does not exists");
            }
            else
            {
                entity = new Account();
                _context.Accounts.AddObject(entity);
            }
        }

        entity.AccountId = business.AccountId;
        entity.AccountText = business.AccountText;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        business.AccountId = entity.AccountId;
        return entity.AccountId;
    }

    public override void Dispose(CommonLib.BusinessModels.Account business)
    {
        long id = business.AccountId;

        Account entity = (from account in _context.Accounts
                          where account.AccountId == id
                          select account).FirstOrDefault();

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Account with id: " + id + " was not found, but an attempt to delete it was done");
        }

        _context.DeleteObject(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But now I would like to use the adapter with linq such that I'm able to do something like

```
AccountEntityAdapter a = new AccountEntityAdapter();
List<Commonlib.BusinessModels.Account> list = (from account in a
                                               where account.AccountId > 6
                                               select account).ToList();
```

Such that I'm free of the Entity Context...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are reinventing a wheel. Give up and use your entities as business objects. What is the point of such extensive complexity?

Comment: As far as i know, the entity objects can't be removed from the app domain, and if I want to transfer the information to another place and then return it with some changes I have to use other objects?

Comment: That is true but the query must run on original objects, not DTOs.

Comment: Exactly, but I want the queries to return my objects instead of the entity objects

Comment: In such case you must do projection in query directly instead of using your mapper otherwise you must run query with entities and after that run linq-to-object query on the result calling your mapper to transform the result.

Comment: Fair enough, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments the options for you are either:

- Doing projection directly in linq-to-entities query instead of using mapper
- Query your entities, call `.ToList` and run linq-to-object query on the result with projecting using your mapper

Answer (score 0):

You need a context to connect to your database. However, usually this is encapsulated in a repository and contained in a central place for use rather than creating one context per action.

Comment: I know, but at the point where I'm using the EntityAdapters I would like that they return my business objects instead of the entity objects. The context is there, but I want the convertion to happen automatically